# Understanding a proof. Why is it necessary that $\alpha<1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm reading the following proof from Lang's book of complex analysis. But I don't know why is it necessary that $\alpha<1$?. I don't know where "$\alpha<1$" is used . I don't understand either why $|g_{\epsilon}(s)|\to 0$ as $|s| \to \infty$. Can you help me, please?. I have been stuck for many hours.

Thank you for any help.

[image]

Comment: The proof starts with "Let $\alpha < \beta < 1$". What happens if $\beta < \alpha$?

Comment: I think that $g_{\epsilon}$ might fail to be bounded on the strip. But, if $\alpha \geq 1$, we could take $\beta \in (\alpha, \alpha+1)$ to show the theorem?

Comment: The proof relies on $0<\beta<1$, since that is a requirement for $\cos(\beta\sigma) > 0$ for all $\sigma\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.